# Keycloak default javascript policy does not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I attempt to use Javascript Policy to do some tests, but the default policy ($evaluation.grant();) does not work in my spring boot API REST.

My configuration spring boot configuration:

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.realm=myrealm
keycloak.resource=mywebservice
keycloak.ssl-required               = external
keycloak.credentials.secret         = mysecret
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = true
keycloak.bearer-only = true
```

My Keycloak Security configuration in spring boot

```
public class SpringKeycloakSecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "keycloak.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
    @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
    public static class KeycloakConfigurationAdapter extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Bean
        @Override
        protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
            return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
        }

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
            keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
            auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
        }

        @Bean
        public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver(){
            return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy())
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

                    .and()
                    .addFilterBefore(keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter(), LogoutFilter.class)
                    .addFilterBefore(keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), X509AuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())

                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
    }
}
```

and my keycloak configuration:

```
{
  "allowRemoteResourceManagement": true,
  "policyEnforcementMode": "ENFORCING",
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "Default Resource",
      "type": "urn:mywebservice:resources:default",
      "ownerManagedAccess": false,
      "attributes": {},
      "_id": "70a6ee62-fa92-4f40-afff-6e196d89f426",
      "uris": [
        "/*"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "policies": [
    {
      "id": "73ff20e1-047f-4c96-a7a5-8b31270c4011",
      "name": "Default Policy",
      "description": "A policy that grants access only for users within this realm",
      "type": "js",
      "logic": "POSITIVE",
      "decisionStrategy": "AFFIRMATIVE",
      "config": {
        "code": "// by default, grants any permission associated with this policy\n$evaluation.deny();\n"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "9c2cf912-64ab-4526-ad3f-0ad277c775e6",
      "name": "Default Permission",
      "description": "A permission that applies to the default resource type",
      "type": "resource",
      "logic": "POSITIVE",
      "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
      "config": {
        "defaultResourceType": "urn:mywebservice:resources:default",
        "applyPolicies": "[\"Default Policy\"]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "scopes": [],
  "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS"
}
```

Basically, it is set to grant(), but to test the configuration, I set it to deny to refuse access.

But does not work, I can access all resources with authentication with bearer token.

I'm sure that is a lack of understanding on my part.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.enforcement-mode=ENFORCING` in the spring boot configuration.